# Evaluate the $\lim_{x\to 0}\cot(2x)^{\frac{5}{\ln(3x)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to evaluate
$\lim_{x \to 0 } \cot(2x)^{\frac{5}{\ln(3x)}}$
My try:
$$\lim_{x \to 0 } \cot(2x)^{\frac{5}{\ln(3x)}} = \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{1}{\sin(2x)}^{\frac{5}{\ln(3x)}} = \lim_{x \to 0 } e^{-5\frac{\ln(\sin(2x)}{\ln(3x)} } = \lim_{x \to 0 } e^{-5\frac{\ln(2x)}{\ln(3x)} }  = e^{-5}$$

It's ok?

Comment: $$\lim_{x \to 0 } \cot(2x)^{\frac{5}{\ln(3x)}} = \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{\cos(2)}{\sin(2x)}^{\frac{5}{\ln(3x)}} = \lim_{x \to 0 } e^{-5\frac{\ln(\sin(2x) - \ln(\cos(2))}{\ln(3x)} } = \lim_{x \to 0 } e^{-5\frac{\ln(2x)}{\ln(3x)} }  = e^{-5}$$

It's ok?

Comment: Yes it looks better now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Find  $5\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\ln \cos(2x) - \ln \sin (2x)}{\ln (3x)}$, and use L'hospitale rule .